# await Task.Delay() doesn't work on Xamarin.iOS using MVVMCross

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, asynchronous, xamarin.ios

I am working on a Xamarin.iOS app using mvvm architecture. The problem is, that if I try to run *await Task.Delay(2000)* in the Initialize method of the main ViewModel class, the app stops on the LaunchScreen without any error messages.
Without that line the app works perfectly.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public override async Task Initialize()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
}
```

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
Initialize is beeing called by MVVMCross after I call *awaitNavigationService.Navigate()*

```
public class CustomAppStart : MvxAppStart
{
    public CustomAppStart(IMvxApplication application, IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(application, navigationService)
    {
    }
    protected override async Task NavigateToFirstViewModel(object hint = null)
    {
        await NavigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>();
    }
}
```

And by the documentation I should be able to use await safely: [MvvmCross ViewModel Lifecycle](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/viewmodel-lifecycle)

Comment: It seems like  dead lock issue. Your main UI thread is blocked by calling Initialize method. Could you show code that calls  Initialize() method ?

Comment: @OlegBondarenko I edited the description.

Comment: Probably you are right about correct calling method Initialize based on documentation. Could you add `await base.Initialize();` inside your override method as first line and before  `await Task.Delay(2000);`?

Comment: @OlegBondarenko Added, but nothing changed :( And now I found a one-year-old github issue with the same problem, and it's still open. I can't believe it :/ [link](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/3209)

Comment: you could use workaround like `Task.Run(async () =>  { Task.Delay(2000); });` in  your Initialize() method . It runs your task outside of UI thread.

Comment: @OlegBondarenko Still the same. But as an alternetive way I placed the "heavy work" (Task.Delay) into the ViewAppearing() method, and it works :) Not the most beautiful way, but working.

Comment: It is a bug I've seen in another project of mine. Probably related to someting inside the MVVMCross Framework. To be clear, you should face this issue ONLY for the default/first viewmodel of your app. For any other viewmodel after the first one, it should work just fine

Comment: You should put in the answer @kistelekig, so that its searchable and SO users know its answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kistelekig pointed out above, he was able to resolve it by placing the task delay in the `ViewAppearing` lifecycle function of the view model instead. So it would look like this

```
public override async Task ViewAppearing()
{
    base.ViewAppearing()
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Fixed it, my bad